# Soldier vs. Warrior

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember a conversation between two characters in an RPG a "Soldier"(Lawful good type)  and a "Warrior" (neutral-evil type).

I don't know the exact dialog but:

**Warrior:**

> Talks about how he is a proud warrior who defeated many enemies.

**Soldier:**

> Angrily calls the warrior out for being little more than a mercenary
> seeing he only fights for personal gain and lacks any sense of greater
> good, instead fighting for payment and pleasure.

**Warrior:**

> Rebukes that the soldier is a mindless drone who does what his
> government tells him  to do and uses his government as a shield to
> avoid personal responsibility for his actions.

After this the soldier seemed to question his personal beliefs and walked away.

It was a RPG game with a party system from about 15 to 20 years ago.

Could anyone point me in the direction of the actual dialog?

My first guess was that it was from Knights Of the Old Republic, with the warrior being Canderous Ordo and the soldier being Carth Onasi, but seeing it was so long ago i might be mixing up games seeing i can't find any dialog between them that sounds like this conversation.

Comment: Is there any science fiction or fantasy to the story?

Comment: @user14111 Edited it, my first guess was Star Wars Knights of the old Republic. i do remember a sci-fi/fantasy setting.

Comment: This is a very generic tropey conversation, is there anything else you remember at all? Otherwise I'm pretty confident any game with those two types of characters has that conversation in it to an extent.

Comment: The soldier-vs-warrior debate certainly shows up in a lot of places in genre literature; off the top of my head Brin has done it (*The Postman*), as have Drake (*Ranks of Bronze*) and Turtledove (*The Lost Legion*).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot only that it was a third person RPG

Comment: Was this RPG on PC? Mac? Playstation/Xbox/N64/other console?

Comment: @AJM it was on PC .